# When using liquibase with mysql, I get No operations allowed after connection closed error

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I use liquibase with maven. When I execute my sql scripts by maven I get `No operations allowed after connection closed` error many times. 
The weird part is, sometimes it works, many time I get this error. Generally it works after I execute it 3-5 times.

After I get the error, I splitted my sql into 5 files. Now I get the error in 4. sql or 5. sql file. It seems randomize.

I use liquibase 3.1.1 version.

Database Connection Configuration:

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ls?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
db.username=root
db.password=
```

Here is my changelog.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="sql-1" author="team" context="db">
        <sqlFile path="schema/model/db-0.0.1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="sql-2" author="team" context="db">
        <sqlFile path="schema/model/db-0.0.2.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="sql-3" author="team" context="db">
        <sqlFile path="schema/model/db-0.0.3.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="sql-4" author="team" context="db">
        <sqlFile path="schema/model/db-0.0.4.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="sql-5" author="team" context="db">
        <sqlFile path="schema/model/db-0.0.5.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8"/>
    </changeSet>

    <include file="etc/db/schema/model/data-0.0.1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE 10/6/14 7:10 PM:liquibase: etc/db/changelog.xml: sql-4::team: Change Set etc/db/changelog.xml::sql-4::team failed.  Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:79)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:61)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:106)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1189)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1172)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:352)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:40)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:64)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseUpdate.doUpdate(LiquibaseUpdate.java:31)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.performLiquibaseTask(AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.java:24)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3234)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:77)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 36 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 36 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:294)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:54)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3573)
    ... 42 more
INFO 10/6/14 7:10 PM:liquibase: etc/db/changelog.xml::sql-4::team: Successfully released change log lock
SEVERE 10/6/14 7:10 PM:liquibase: etc/db/changelog.xml::sql-4::team: Could not release lock
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:234)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:206)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseUpdate.doUpdate(LiquibaseUpdate.java:31)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.performLiquibaseTask(AbstractLiquibaseUpdateMojo.java:24)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(StandardLockService.java:136)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.releaseLock(StandardLockService.java:224)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.TableSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(TableSnapshotGenerator.java:43)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:59)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:47)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:131)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:36)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:24)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:129)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:137)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.has(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:91)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:169)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(StandardLockService.java:134)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:3234)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.getMetaData(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:35)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.TableSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(TableSnapshotGenerator.java:31)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 36 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 36 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:294)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:54)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:106)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1189)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1172)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:352)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:40)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:64)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3573)
    ... 42 more
WARNING 10/6/14 7:10 PM:liquibase: etc/db/changelog.xml::sql-4::team: Failed to restore the auto commit to true
```

Comment: I had alter scripts for foreign keys. When I removed my foreign keys everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this same error with liquibase 3.1.1 without maven. Obviously it has to do with mysql closing the connection because it has been inactive for to long, but how to avoid it in liquibase is something i would also like to see answered.

Comment: Liquibase does nothing special with the connection. I don't see a mysql connection URL setting to configure it, but there is a system-side wait_timeout setting.

It looks like your connection was last used 36ms ago, so it seems strange that it would timeout. Perhaps a network issue?